While using provider it shows Error: Can't declare a member that conflicts with an inherited one
In code there is no error but while running it, it shows the following error:
Error: Can't declare a member that conflicts with an inherited one.
./../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/provider-5.0.0/lib/src/selector.dart:65:22: Error: Can't declare a member that conflicts with an inherited one.
_Selector0State createState() => _Selector0State();
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:808:13: Context: This is the inherited member.
State get createState;
^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

